# Write access in char array

Tags: c++, pointers, reverse

everyone!

I'm writing a simple char* string reverse. I get an error with writing access in line `src[k] = src[n - k];` when I initialize my input array as a pointer : `char * input= "string"`.
And it is fixed, when I put: `char input[] = "string"`;

Why doesn't it work with a pointer? Thanks a lot!

Here is my code:

```
void reverse(char* src) {
    if (src == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    size_t n = strlen(src) - 1;
    char swap;
    for (int k = 0; k <= n/2; k++) {
        swap = src[k];
        src[k] = src[n - k];
        src[n - k] = swap;
    }
    src[n + 1] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: `char* input= "string";` will not compile in C++11 without giving diagnostic (in this form of *error* or at least *warning*).

Comment: @Nawaz, I thought it had to give an error.

Comment: @chris - the only thing that's required to produce an error (as in, compiler refuses to compile the code) is a `#error` directive. In general, the requirement is that the compiler issue "a diagnostic", after which it is free to continue compilation, giving the code whatever meaning it wants. That's the hook for compiler-specific extensions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work with the pointer because the pointer points to the literal `"string"`. String literals are not modifiable. When you use an array, the literal is copied into the array, which is modifiable.